# Leaflet Ruler check if the ruler is in use

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I don't have much experience with Leaflet and I'm using the ruler from [here](https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler). I'm trying to find out if it's in use when the map zoom changes.

```
var rulerOptions = {
position: 'topright',         
circleMarker: {              
    color: 'black',
    radius: 2
},
lineStyle: {                  
    color: 'red',
    dashArray: '1,6'
},
lengthUnit: { 
    display: 'km',
    decimal: 2,
    label: 'Distance:'
}
};
L.control.ruler(rulerOptions).addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
//is ruler on?
});
```

I've searched for something like `ruler.on('click', function (){ //do something });` but I didn't find anything that helped me.

Is there a way to know if the ruler is in use (the ruler button is pressed and you can perform measuring on the map - I've seen that the button has color when active and is black and white when inactive)?

Comment: Does "in use" mean that the button is active? Or something else?

Comment: @toms I mean when the ruler button is pressed and when you click on the map, you are actually measuring distances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the internals of the leaflet-ruler plugin, there is property `._choice` set to `true` when control is active. Property `._polylineLayer` points to feature group containing already drawn measuring segments.

Code for checking plugin activity status could then look something like this:

```
var rulerControl = L.control.ruler(rulerOptions).addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
  var rulerActive = rulerControl._choice;
  console.log('Ruler is active: ', rulerActive);
  if (rulerActive) {
    var nSegments = rulerControl._polylineLayer.getLayers().length;
    console.log('Drawn segements: ', nSegments);
  }
});
```